# Outlier Detection By Dummy Regression Models

Tags: r, regression, time-series, econometrics, outliers

The standard procedure for outlier detection in time series implemented in almost all statistical
software tools is based on regression the time series to candidate regression variables. These
regression variables differs is case of additive outliers (AO) and level shifts which are often named innovational outliers (IO) in this context. An additive outlier concern to a measurement error whereas an innovential outlier represents an extraordinary shock at time point t influencing the values at time points $t + 1, \dots,T$.

The differential model: Despite of the given models in literature, we define a simplified model
which are not based on complex model estimation, which is not very applicable when dealing with
short time series. We define the model as follows:

$$y_{t_d} = \beta \zeta_t + \epsilon_t,$$
where $y_{t_d}$ is the vector of differentiated values $y_{t_d} = \Delta^d y_t = y_{t+1} - y_t$ for $t = 1,\dots,T-1$. $\beta$ are the regression coefficients and
$$\zeta_t = \begin{cases}
      1, & \text{if}\ t=T \\
      0, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}$$

How would I implement this in R? Is someone aware of a package where this is implemented?

Comment: `The standard procedure for outlier detection in time series implemented in almost all statistical software tools...` citation needed. I am not aware of any such standard procedure, and I would be worried if this were a standard.